# Not authorized for collection query Mongo Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am deploying a Flask app on Heroku with a Mongo database.

When I query a collection stored in the database, the following error returns:

```
database error: not authorized for query on db.collection
```

The following code creates my mongo instance:

```
 MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://username:password@dshost.mongolab.com:host/db_name'
 mongo = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
```

I got my MONGODB_URI from the following code:

```
$ heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI
```

And then I query the collection with the following code, within one of the views:

```
x = mongo.db.collection.find()
```

Am I missing a step of authorization somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Needed to call

```
x = mongo.db_name.collection.find()
```